# Jquery audio player linke soundclound with waveform

Tags: jquery, html

i'm currently using http://jplayer.org/, and it's working great for my needs but now I'll need something more advanced.

I was wondering if any of you guys know a audio plugin similar to soundclound:

https://soundcloud.com/boris-johnson-vs-2anondjs/boris-johnson-vs-2-anonymous-djs-is-fatboy-slim-a-dj-sample

with controls in the wave form and etc.

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this work: http://codecanyon.net/item/zoomsounds-neat-html5-audio-player/4525354

Comment: Thanks man, this will do the job.